# HuggingFace - How to plot training and validation accuracy vs. Epoch graph?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

As the title is self-descriptive, I need to plot the training and validation accuracy obtained during the training of my Hugging Face model. After that, I'd like to plot the confusion matrix for the test predictions. How can I do these?

Here is my training arguments:

```
args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=f"my_training",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    num_train_epochs=5,
    warmup_ratio=0.1,
    logging_steps=10,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="accuracy",
    report_to='tensorboard',
    push_to_hub=True,
)
```

And, here is my trainer:

```
def compute_metrics(eval_pred):
    predictions = np.argmax(eval_pred.predictions, axis=1)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_pred=predictions, y_true=eval_pred.label_ids)
    return {"accuracy": accuracy}


trainer = Trainer(
    model,
    args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    tokenizer=processor,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    data_collator=collate_fn
)
```

Finally, I start the training and prediction, respectively:

```
train_results = trainer.train()
trainer.save_model()
trainer.log_metrics("train", train_results.metrics)
trainer.save_metrics("train", train_results.metrics)
trainer.save_state()

eval_results = trainer.evaluate(eval_dataset)
trainer.log_metrics("eval", eval_results)
trainer.save_metrics("eval", eval_results)
```

With the current configuration, I only get the eval/accuracy vs. Steps graph.